# Many to many in Mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, rubygems, sinatra, mongoid

Yes, I know how to create many to many  relationships but nothing else. I did a google search and read official mongoid documentation but I didn't anything about how to work with it. By work I mean inserting, updating, deleting, finding, counting...

For example, suppose I have 2 models (from documentation):

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tag
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bands
end
```

What should I do to make all the operations I mentioned above?

P.S. I use Sinatra and mongoid 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Inserting

From the documentation table immediately following your sample models (plus my comment).

```
# Create a tag for a band
band.tags.create(name: "electro")
```

## Finding

Also from the same table.

```
# Find a tag that belongs to that band, whose name is "electro"
tag = band.tags.where(name: "electro")
```

## Updating

From the doc on [persistence](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html), modified for the band/tags example.

```
# using variable tag from previous line.
tag.update_attributes(name: "dubstep")
```

## Counting

From the doc on [querying](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html), which also contains information useful for the other items here (also modified).

```
band.tags.length
```

## Deleting

This is from the persistence document also.

```
# we will delete the tag from earlier
tag.delete
```

### Lastly

All the information needed to work Mongoid is in the [docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/), which are actually very thorough and useful. There is definitely a lot, but you can make it through it in a couple hours.

Comment: Why did not I find it? Hmmmm.

Comment: What would happen if I did `tags.create(name: "electro")` instead of `band.tags.create(name: "electro")`?